# chomp seems to clean up the entire string or prevent it from being printed

Tags: perl

I was following a Perl tutorial when I found out a quite odd behavior and couldn't figure why. I'm currently on Ubuntu 18.04 and using the standard Perl distributed with it, version 5.26.1, and with output buffering turned off

```
$|=1;
```

At one point in my script where I type

```
<INPUT>;
while(my $line = <INPUT>){
    # chomp($line);
    print "before $line after";
}
```

I get the result

> before Isaac Newton, 99.10 , 15051999
>    afterbefore Albert Einstein,13.20,11062012
>    afterbefore Carl Scheele,66.23,01012000
>    afterbefore Rene Descartes,0.57,10072033
>    after[my prompt]

by uncommenting `chomp` I then get

> after[my prompt]

For testing the record separator, I've substituted the inner block as follows

```
<INPUT>;
while(my $line = <INPUT>){

    print "blah";
    print "$/";
    print "blah\n";
}
```

and the result was

> blah
>   blah
>   blah
>   blah
>   blah
>   blah
>   blah
>   blah
>   [my prompt]

I don't know why chomp is preventing everything from being printed, besides, for what it seems, the very last " after". Does anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @toolic suggestion, I noticed the file was prepared in Windows. Hexpumping it showed the characters *0d* and *0a*  at the end of each string. `chomp` was probably removing only the new line character and the carriage return was, apart from the very last string, resetting the output stream to the first position. This was the reason for the odd output.
His suggestion worked as well.
Since I want to use `split` down the road, I opted to set the record separator  to `\r\n`.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your file has Windows line endings (CR+LF), but you are using a Unix system (no CR+LF⇒LF conversion layer added by default), so you are ending up with CR-terminated lines.

You should fix the file using a tool like `dos2unix`.

Alternatively, replace `chomp;` with `s/\s+\z//;`.